# How can two nodelets in one process publish diagnostics?

Tags: ros, diagnostics, diagnostic-aggregator, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thomas Moulard and I recently [added diagnostic monitoring](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5292) to the `camera1394` driver.

It seems to work, but he discovered that when two instances of the driver nodelet are running in the same process, only one gets its diagnostics published.

I believe this is because information in the `/diagnositics` topic is prefixed by the node name, which seems to come from the nodelet manager process, not the driver nodelet.

Is there some way to make this work correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28645/how-can-two-nodelets-in-one-process-publish-diagnostics?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not really a solution. I worked around the same issue last week by ensuring that each of my nodelets stored a unique string identifier coming from the name under which it was launched. e.g. "goo_base" in

We pulled that name from the nodehandle and then simple applied that to the name when adding a task to the diagnostic_updater:

`this->diagnostic_updater.add("firmware [") + unresolved_name + std::string("]"), this, &GooNodelet::firmwareDiagnostic);`

It would be nice if diagnostics pulled that unresolved name directly.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2